# Chrome rendering issue?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm using Chrome 53.0.2785.143 and I came across a rendering issue that seemed to happen more frequently on my application when using CSS transform scale.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/itayad/f3s7om15/) which shows the issue, try to scroll down all the way, eventually you'll reach a stage where nothing will be rendered. On Firefox this JSFiddle will work fine.

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
Rendering issue 
...
...
(you need to repeat this ~75000 times)
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
  width: 600px;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

I'm wondering if anyone else came across this issue, and knows how to deal with it.

Comment: Well, reproduced on latest chrome.

Comment: Firefox 49 also seems to take a while to render it

Comment: Also seems to occur in Edge (Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393). Is [this (img)](http://i.imgur.com/Fwm3UPb.png) what you are talking about?

Comment: Yeah seems slightly different though, also it actually seem to occur also in Firefox but differently as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this issue to Chromium and they answered back that this example does reach a paint limit. [Link to issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=654433)

"The computed height on the div is 1.725e+07px, so it's not surprising we stop rendering it. We do render something up to 1.665e+07px.

This is WontFix. At some point we need to limit the size of the painted area, and this seems reasonable."